# Julia: short syntax for creating (1,n) array

Tags: julia

In Matlab I can write:

```
[0:n]
```

to get an array (1,n). For n=2, I get:

```
  0     1     2
```

How to do the same in Julia? The purpose is to get the same type of array (1,3).

I know I can write [0 1 2], but I want something general like in Matlab.

Comment: You can try `hcat(1:n...)` to get an array and `[1:n;].'` to get a `RowVector`.

Comment: Take a look at `collect`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In julia, the colon operator (in this context, anyway) returns a `UnitRange` object. This is an iterable object; that means you can use it with a for loop, or you can `collect` all its contents, etc. If you collect its contents, what you get here is a Vector.

If what you're after is explicitly a *RowVector*, then you can collect the contents of the UnitRange, and reshape the resulting vector accordingly (which in this case can be done via a simple transpose operation).

```
julia> collect(1:3).'
1×3 RowVector{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 1  2  3
```

The `.'` transpose operator is also defined for UnitRange arguments:

```
julia> (1:3).'
1×3 RowVector{Int64,UnitRange{Int64}}:
 1  2  3
```

However, note the difference in the resulting type; if you apply `.'` again, you get a UnitRange object back again.

If you don't particularly like having a "RowVector" object, and want a straightforward array, use that in an Array constructor:

```
julia> Array((1:3).')
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
```

---

<sub>(above as of latest julia 0.7 dev version)</sub>

Comment: Adding an update from 2022: `.'` is now deprecated, all you need is `collect(1:3)`. This returns `3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3`

Comment: @TrevorGross thanks for the update! Any idea what it has been replaced with? The deprecation error is extremely inadequate, and the in-REPL documentation still mentions `.'` like nothing's changed ‍♂️